# Возможные проблемы с proguard

Tags: android, исключения, proguard

Сегодня решил сделать релизную версию. Оказалось, что proguard что-то режет. Сразу скажу, что ни один из потерянных классов мне не знаком, да и код я с последнего релиза не сильно менял, а ведь тогда он работал! Подскажите, что добавить в proguard, чтобы этот зверь снова заработал?

Ниже привожу **exception** потерянных классов:

```
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find superclass or interface com.sun.msv.datatype.SerializationContext  
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find superclass or interface org.relaxng.datatype.ValidationContext 
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find superclass or interface com.sun.msv.datatype.SerializationContext    
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find superclass or interface org.relaxng.datatype.ValidationContext   
org.dom4j.swing.XMLTableDefinition: can't find superclass or interface org.jaxen.VariableContext    
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultNamespaceContext: can't find superclass or interface org.jaxen.NamespaceContext  
org.dom4j.xpp.ProxyXmlStartTag: can't find superclass or interface org.gjt.xpp.XmlStartTag  
library class org.xml.sax.ext.Attributes2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Attributes    
library class org.xml.sax.ext.Attributes2Impl extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl    
library class org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler    
library class org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler    
library class org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.ext.DeclHandler   
library class org.xml.sax.ext.EntityResolver2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.EntityResolver    
library class org.xml.sax.ext.Locator2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Locator  
library class org.xml.sax.ext.Locator2Impl extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.helpers.LocatorImpl  
library class org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Locator    
library class org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.XMLReader  
library class org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Attributes 
ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.JMXConfiguratorAction: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory   
ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluatorBase: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.janino.ExpressionEvaluator    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException  
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException  
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor  
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.MethodDescriptor    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor  
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.MethodDescriptor    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor  
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.MethodDescriptor    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo    
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException  
ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor  
com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.Registration: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getTextContent()' in program class org.w3c.dom.Node   
javassist.tools.rmi.ObjectImporter: can't find referenced class java.applet.Applet  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector$Argument   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector    
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.IllegalConnectorArgumentsException   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector$Argument   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap    
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachineManager    
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector    
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.MethodEntryRequest   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.ReferenceType    
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.MethodEntryRequest   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue 
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.MethodEntryRequest   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector    
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.MethodEntryRequest   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.MethodEntryRequest   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.MethodEntryRequest   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager  
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.MethodEntryRequest   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.ReferenceType    
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventSet   
javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue 
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventSet 
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventIterator    
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.MethodEntryEvent 
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.Event    
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventSet 
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.Event    
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventIterator    
javassist.util.HotSwapper$1: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.event.EventSet 
org.dom4j.DocumentFactory: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.VariableContext    
org.dom4j.DocumentHelper: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.VariableContext 
org.dom4j.XPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.FunctionContext  
org.dom4j.XPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.NamespaceContext 
org.dom4j.XPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.VariableContext  
org.dom4j.bean.BeanMetaData: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException  
org.dom4j.bean.BeanMetaData: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector    
org.dom4j.bean.BeanMetaData: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo    
org.dom4j.bean.BeanMetaData: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor  
org.dom4j.bean.BeanMetaData: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo    
org.dom4j.bean.BeanMetaData: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException  
org.dom4j.bean.BeanMetaData: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor  
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.SerializationContext 
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.ValidationContext    
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype   
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException    
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype   
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException    
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.DatabindableDatatype 
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype   
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException    
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeAttribute: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.DatabindableDatatype 
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.SerializationContext   
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.ValidationContext  
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.DatabindableDatatype   
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype 
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException  
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype 
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException  
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype 
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.DatabindableDatatype   
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElement: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException  
org.dom4j.datatype.DatatypeElementFactory: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype  
org.dom4j.datatype.NamedTypeResolver: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype   
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException 
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.TypeIncubator 
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException 
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype    
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.DatatypeFactory   
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype    
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException 
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype    
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.TypeIncubator 
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.ValidationContext 
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype    
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class org.relaxng.datatype.DatatypeException 
org.dom4j.datatype.SchemaParser: can't find referenced class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype    
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserException  
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParser   
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserFactory    
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParser   
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserFactory    
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlEndTag   
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParser   
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserFactory    
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParser   
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserFactory    
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParser   
org.dom4j.io.XPPReader: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlEndTag   
org.dom4j.rule.Stylesheet: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.XPath  
org.dom4j.swing.DocumentTreeModel: can't find referenced method 'void setRoot(javax.swing.tree.TreeNode)' in program class org.dom4j.swing.DocumentTreeModel    
org.dom4j.swing.XMLTableDefinition: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.VariableContext   
org.dom4j.util.ProxyDocumentFactory: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.VariableContext  
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultNamespaceContext: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.NamespaceContext 
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.XPath   
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleNamespaceContext  
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.XPath   
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException  
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.XPath   
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.dom4j.Dom4jXPath    
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException  
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.XPath   
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.NamespaceContext    
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.FunctionContext 
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.NamespaceContext    
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.VariableContext 
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException  
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.XPath   
org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException  
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.pattern.Pattern 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.Context 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.saxpath.SAXPathException    
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.pattern.PatternParser   
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.saxpath.SAXPathException    
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException  
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.Context 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.pattern.Pattern 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.Context 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.ContextSupport  
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleNamespaceContext  
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.XPathFunctionContext    
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.SimpleVariableContext   
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.dom4j.DocumentNavigator 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.ContextSupport  
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.pattern.Pattern 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.Context 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.pattern.Pattern 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.saxpath.SAXPathException    
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException  
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.pattern.Pattern 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.VariableContext 
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.ContextSupport  
org.dom4j.xpath.XPathPattern: can't find referenced class org.jaxen.JaxenException  
org.dom4j.xpp.ProxyXmlStartTag: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlStartTag 
org.dom4j.xpp.ProxyXmlStartTag: can't find referenced class org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserException  
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String REQUESTED_API_VERSION' in program class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder    
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory: can't find referenced method 'org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder getSingleton()' in program class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder 
library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xml.sax.ContentHandler  
there were 316 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.  
there were 14 instances of library classes depending on program classes.    
there were 4 unresolved references to program class members.    
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Вот такая вот простыня... Попробовал добавить костыльный hotfix:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
     *;
}
```

но это не помогло. Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как ее можно быстро решить?

Comment: Если быстро надо, можно попытаться все игнорить. Не все ваши зависимости 100% совместимы с Андроид. Некоторых классов нет в принципе, а не потому что proguard вырезал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в следующем: один из разработчиков заиспользовал для своей версии reflections из java, которая была подключена с помощью maven. Он использовал ее в своем productFlavors, но подключил в общий gradle файл. В общем удалив это безобразие, мы получили рабочую сборку! Если что, такую ошибку вызывает:

```
implementation group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.5-RC2'
```

Спасибо всем за участие!